# Compile Issues with OpenJDK and iText example

Tags: java, itext, hsm

I have problems to [compiling this example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/itext/i5js-tutorial/master/signatures/src/main/java/signatures/chapter4/C4_01_SignWithPKCS11HSM.java)

I am Using OpenJDK on Mac: openjdk version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16

Main Issue:
The import sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 cannot be resovled

Minor Issue:
The constructor OcspClientBouncyCastle() is depricated

What are the workarounds and would it be possible to update the example?

Comment: iText 7 is compiled with jdk-8-oracle, with target JDK 7 and runtime of JDK 7, and is tested against jre-7-oracle, jre-8-oracle, jre-9-oracle, jre-10-oracle, jre-10-openjdk, jre-11-openjdk, jre-12-openjdk, jre-13-openjdk. However, the example you are referring to, is for iText 5 and is deprecated. That being said, you error is most likely related to using an incompatible version of BouncyCastle. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As for your main issue, might consider changing your approach, as per information on here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html

Related to Minor and still related to Main issues, you are using old libraries, you can't fix the deprecated error, you either live with it, or you find the library or version of the library that will fix the issue.

Just a word of advice, when dealing with old libraries, updating could mean a change to your entire solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should also specify what version of iText and BouncyCastle you are trying to use.

Regarding your main issue, are you simply trying to compile/run the example, or do you have a specific PKCS11 provider and configuration in mind? Handling of the PKCS11 provider has changed in recent JDK releases. You can get more info starting here:

- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8046121

Regarding your minor issue and assuming using a recent release of BouncyCastle, you can do this to avoid the deprecation warning:

```
        OCSPVerifier ocspVerifier = new OCSPVerifier(null, null);
        OcspClient  ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle(ocspVerifier);
```

See here for the ramifications:

- [iTextSharp OcspClientBouncyCastle constructor is deprecated, what's the replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40765907/itextsharp-ocspclientbouncycastle-constructor-is-deprecated-whats-the-replacem)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your Input! After the comment of kaliatech I realized that there are specific libraries for PKCS11 from the HSM provider which I could use.
@Estevao Santiago: Thanks for the link and the way on how to use OSCP client correctly.

I finally used JAVA JCE/JCA, instead of the PKCS11 approach. For me it seems to be a much simpler approach to use the HSM. I just added the correct JAR of the HSM device and registered the security provider of the HSM.