# Which certificates are required for iText.Signatures.OcspClientBouncyCastle GetEncoded

Tags: pdf, itext, itext7, sign

I want to set the ocsp when signing pdf document using iText

The ocsp is created using the following code:

```
            OCSPVerifier ocspVerifier = new OCSPVerifier(null, null); // can be null based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40765907/itextsharp-ocspclientbouncycastle-constructor-is-deprecated-whats-the-replacem
            IOcspClient ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle(ocspVerifier);
            var test = ocspClient.GetEncoded(rootCertificate, cert, "http://my-url.com");
```

The result of this code is null.
I guess it's because i set the wrong certificates.

The first parameter is named **checkCert** and the second one **issuerCert**
Note: I'm using iText version 7.1. It seems the names were changed to checkCert/rootCert in version 7.7

What exactly are checkCert and issuerCert?
I tried with the signing root certificate as checkCert and the signature certificate as issuerCert but it doesn't work.

Any idea or explanation which certificates are required here?

Edit:
The following is the code which i use to create the pkcs7 container which should include the ocsp:

```
            OCSPVerifier ocspVerifier = new OCSPVerifier(null, null); // null,null >https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40765907/itextsharp-ocspclientbouncycastle-constructor-is-deprecated-whats-the-replacem
            IOcspClient ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle(ocspVerifier);
            var ocsp = ocspClient.GetEncoded(cert, rootCertificate, "http://www.my.com/aia/ocsp");
            if (ocsp == null)
                Console.WriteLine("oscp is null");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("ocsp is not null");


            //Create the pkcs7 container
            PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, c.ToArray(), HashAlgorithm, false);
            byte[] sh = sgn.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, ocsp, null, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);

            //Load the signature via pkcs11 hardware
            byte[] extSignature = GetSignatureFromHashViaPkcs11(sh, pin);

            sgn.SetExternalDigest(extSignature, null, DigestEncryptionAlgorithm);
            var ret = sgn.GetEncodedPKCS7(hash, tsaClient, ocsp, null, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

No matter how i set the certificates in ocspClient.GetEncoded, the resulting ocsp is always null

Even a more fundamental question: Are the issuer and root certificate the certificates i use for creating the signature or are those the certificates from the ocsp?

Comment: First of all it normally isn't you who has to explicitly call `IOcspClient` methods but it's the iText signing code (`PdfSigner.SignDetached`); you merely have to supply an implementation, usually `OcspClientBouncyCastle`. Thus, I don't understand how your code relates to your objective _to set the ocsp when signing pdf document using iText_.

Comment: That been said, the first parameter of `GetEncoded` is the certificate you want to retrieve revocation information for, and the second parameter is the issuer certificate for the first one.

Comment: As an aside, there is no iText version 7.7 yet, at least not by the iText people themselves.

Comment: I'm using SignDeferred for signing and i think the ocsp needs to be set in GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes as well as in GetEncodedPKCS7 but i'm unable to create it so far. I'll try to enhance and clarify my question. About version 7.7, you're right, this is my bad.

Comment: I've tried to enhance the question

Comment: Problem was me using the wrong certificates. I had to use the certificates from the OCSP instead of my signing certificates. I now still have the problem that the LTV is not enabled: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67296276/howto-sign-a-pdf-using-itext-which-contains-an-ocsp-which-is-embedded